# Drive Manager (SSH) public key denied connecting to EC2 instance (Mac OSX 10.9)

Tags: macos, ssh, amazon-ec2, sftp

I'm trying to SSH into an EC2 instances via Drive manager using my Mac. I've done this before with another instance, but I set up a new one and can't remember the simple steps I did last time.

I give the server name and username in Drive Manager, but do I need to add my private key or something somewhere else on my computer, e.g., `~/.ssh` directory? If so, how do I locate my private key? Can this be done on AWS management console? My computer is cluttered with keys as I've learned along the way, so I'm simply having trouble re-tracing my steps.

Comment: Please move your question to [su]. It's off-topic here.

Answer (score 0):

I answered my own question. In ExpandDrive Manager there is a more "options" menu. If you click that, there will be a dropdown where you can choose to connect with password or your private key. You can then select your private key from the finder menu, which in my case is located in `~/.ssh`.